# Redux - Understanding advanced mapStateToProps returning a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to understand the mechanics of mapStateToProps when it returns a function.

So I can't find much documentation except a short excerpt from the Redux docs that says in advance cases by returning a function, each instance will get its own memoized mapStateToProps and another user saying that this is an optimisation that prevents mapStateToProps being called for any parent prop changes.

So this seems great for list items, where I would't want to re-render large list of items for any changes that doesn't affect an item.

So the part that confuses me is that mapStateToProps won't be called for any parent prop changes, does that mean in order for an individual list 'Item' to be re-rendered it needs to be a smart connected component for it to pick up changes it cares about and re-render? Or does that mean it will never re-render for this particular Item instance?

**Update:**

Wanted to clarify that I am talking specifically about the factory function version of mapStateProps.

Here is the feature I am talking about, taken from React-Redux docs:

*Note: in advanced scenarios where you need more control over the rendering performance, mapStateToProps() can also return a function. In this case, that function will be used as mapStateToProps() for a particular component instance. This allows you to do per-instance memoization. You can refer to #279 and the tests it adds for more details. Most apps never need this.*

And paragraph taken from this article:

https://medium.com/@cvetanov/redux-mapstatetoprops-optimization-5880078a8a7a

*If redux receives an implementation which returns a function it performs a closure for wrapping the own props of the component and therefore bypasses the invocation of the mapStateToProps every time the component changes it’s props received from the parent component. It creates a so called purePropsSelector. How this is done can be seen here.*

**Update 2:**

Right I am investigating the article that mentions the skipping, it seems to be when you wrap the own props in a closure and return a function that only uses the state. So it prevents the mapStateToProps being invoked when the parent props changes for each 'connected' child item.

This is taken from that medium article I read above:

```
function mapStateToPropsFactory(initialState, ownProps) {
  // a closure for ownProps is created
  // this factory is not invoked everytime the component
  // changes it's props
  return function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      blogs:
        state.blogs.filter(blog => blog.author === ownProps.user)
    };
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToPropsFactory)(MyBlogs);
```

Answer (score 13):

Every `mapStateToProps` function will always be called if the state changes. There is no mechanism included in redux that prevents `mapStateToProps` from being called.

> [From the docs for `connect()`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options):
>
> `mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps] (Function)`: If this argument is specified, the new component will subscribe to Redux store updates. This means that **any time the store is updated, mapStateToProps will be called**.

What you want to prevent (usually by using selectors) is that expensive computations happening inside `mapStateToProps` will be repeated on every state update even if they produce the same result.

> Or does that mean it will never re-render for this particular Item
>   instance?

It will re-render as usual if any props received by the connected component change. The point is to prevent `mapStateToProps` from doing expensive calculations. `mapStateToProps` is dumb. It does its calculations and passes them to the connected component as props. The component then checks if the props differ from the previous ones and decides to re-render based on that.

Consider this `mapStateToProps` function which uses a selector `getVisibleTodos`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
}
```

Selectors memorize the result of a call and will simply return that result on subsequent calls as long as the input parameters do not change. The selector in this example only gets its input from the redux state. As long as `state.todos` and `state.visibilityFilter` do not change it can use the memorized result from the last call and does not need to recompute something.

Now consider this another example:

```
const TodoList = ({id, todos}) => (
  <ul id={id}>
    {todos.map(/* ... */)}
  </ul>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state, props)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList);
```

This time the selector additionally takes the components own props as input. This is problematic because if we use two instances of the connected `TodoList` and render it like

```
<TodoList id="list1" />
<TodoList id="list2" />
```

this will cause `mapStateToProps` to be called twice on state updates, one time for each `TodoList` instance. And both times it will receive different props. One time with `{id: 'list1'}` and the second time with `{id: 'list2'}`. But both components share the same selector. This will lead to a re-computation by the selector even if the `todos` for each individual `TodoList` did not change. Now the `mapStateToProps` function that returns a function by itself comes into play:

```
const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
  const getVisibleTodos = makeGetVisibleTodos() // this creates a new selector function
  const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
      todos: getVisibleTodos(state, props)
    }
  }
  return mapStateToProps
}
```

This creates an individual `mapStateToProps` function for each instance of `TodoList` which has its own selector so that it memorizes the props for each instance individually and will only re-compute if props for the instance it was created for change. This will solve the issue from the previous example.

So tl;dr;: When a selector inside `mapStateToProps` takes the own props of the connected component as a parameter you need to use the `mapStateToProps` as a factory to allow for per-instance memorization.

You can find a more detailed explanation with an example under [Comuting Derived Data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data) in the redux docs.

Comment: "Selectors memorize the result of the last call" - if you're using a library like [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect).

Comment: @TrueWill You could easily write a vanilla javascript function that does that and call it a selector. But you are right, `reselect` can help you creating those selectors.

Comment: I have updated my question on specifically what I am talking

Comment: @iQ. My last example is exactly this. And I also explained why you sometimes need it.

Comment: So what about the point regarding mapStateToProps invocation being skipped? That is the part I am unsure about.

Comment: @iQ. Invocation of `mapStateToProps` is **never** skipped. I wrote that in the very beginning. It will always be called for every component that is connected. There is no exception from that. At least not built into redux.

Comment: Ok I have done more investigation and maybe getting somewhere, updated my question. It seems to be a special case when you wrap the ownProps into a closure and return a function that only uses state so it prevents invocation on parent prop changes for each connected child, at least thats what I think it is saying.

Comment: @iQ. Yeah I did a little more research too and I think I now know what you mean. And you are correct. `mapStateToProps` will not be called for  `prop` changes coming from the parent if you use a closure. But it will still be called for every state change. I will edit my answer to add that special case together with a codesandbox example that demonstrates this.

Comment: Instead of creating a factory you could use [re-reselect](https://github.com/toomuchdesign/re-reselect), which allows you to switch/pass more args to your function without losing memoization.

Comment: @TheNastyOne Didn't know about that yet. Thanks for the input. For more advanced scenarios this might be a better fit.

Comment: @trixn the function returned from factory is actually consider as mapStateToProps after the component is initialized, so the returned function will get called for parent props changes, there is no escape from mapStateToProps being called after store state change.

Comment: @JayBidwai Is this in any way different to what I said?

Comment: @trixn you said "And you are correct. mapStateToProps will not be called for prop changes coming from the parent if you use a closure." but I think it will get called for props changes too

Comment: @JayBidwai I if understood it correctly this is not true. React-redux uses a selector to decide whether or not mapStateToProps has to be called on ownProps changes. The relevant code can be found [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/wrapMapToProps.js#L15). In other words, mapStateToProps will only be called on ownProps changes, if one of the selected values from them have changed. Otherwise it will skip calling mapStateToProps.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of `ownProps` is the props that were passed to the component that you are wrapping. You mentioned list items so let's call it `(ListItem)`.

So the `ListItem` component, when its displayed on the screen is passed some library of lists, for example,

`const { id, title } = this.props.library;`

The `ownProps` object is exactly equal to `this.props` inside the component.

So any item you pass into the component will show up in the `mapStateToProps` as `ownProps`. By getting access to `ownProps` inside of this `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { selectedLibraryId: state.selectedLibraryId };
};
```

You can predetermine exactly what props you want to pass down inside your component and this allows you to remove all logic from your component entirely like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const selected = state.selectedLibraryId === ownProps.library.id;
  return { selected };
};
```

The component no longer needs to worry about the meaning of `selectedLibraryId`, it can just look at the `{ selected }` and decide whether or not to show the details of the selected item from the list.